# Access to the path 'autorun.inf' is denied when File.Copy is executed

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, windows

I get the following exception when I try to copy a file in my Windows Application...

**Access to the path 'autorun.inf' is denied.**

The file I am trying to copy is a shortcut file. However when I move the EXACT line of code in a standalone application, it executes flawlessly. Same user credentials. There is no difference on how I launch either application.

This is the line of code...

```
File.Copy(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath), "JEE Startup.lnk"), @"C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\JEE Startup.lnk", true);
```

I tried deleting the bin folder and rebuilding. No luck.

I have no idea what is wrong.

The application is being executed on an XP machine.

Comment: Are you certain that that exact line of code is the culprit? You make no reference to autorun.inf, which makes me think you may have a different problem.

Comment: Its the exact same code. I cut and pasted...

Comment: So that line works when you cut and paste, but didn't work in your function, how does that prove it is the culprit?

Comment: It doesnt... which is why i am asking on here because i dont know why its not working.

Comment: Unless you have found a very weird corner case, that line is not the one that is causing your problems. Look at the other parts of your program to see if maybe a different line is causing the exception you are seeing.